# Pass ownership of an answer to another user

Tags: discussion, answers, users, attribution

**Give credit where credit is due!**

I recently got an upvote on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51932311/8344060). There is nothing special about the answer; I just help someone out. However, this answer is largely based on the content of an [answer on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4658/273492), as is referenced in the answer.

The user of the answer on Unix & Linux is also a user here on Stack Overflow, and I was wondering if I could pass ownership of the answer to that particular user.

Even though the answer in question could just have been a comment and has just received a single upvote, I would not be surprised if other people have similar thoughts and use cases where an ownership transfer would make sense.

So my topic of discussion would be:

- Is a transfer of ownership of answers useful/wanted/overkill?
- How would one implement it (e.g., by a two-party consent)?
- What other examples of use cases would there be?
- Could it be also be applied to questions?

Comment: If you feel "bad" about getting the rep, just make it a CW... If you're also a user on Linux (with some rep to spare), you can offer a bounty for the original answer

Comment: I would love to have this feature so I can transfer my downvote magnets onto your account ....

Comment: If you're interested, I can make it Community Wiki for you

Comment: If you had wanted them to get credit, you could have pinged them in a comment on one of their answers to answer that question. I'm just saying that you had opportunities to allow the user to answer themselves rather than answering it yourself. Also, if the question was already answered on [unix.se], why not migrate it?

Comment: @HereticMonkey _"if the question was already answered on Unix & Linux, why not migrate it?"_ You want to migrate a duplicate?

Comment: @HereticMonkey is the question off-topic here?

Comment: Your answer received a single upvote nearly 3 years after it was posted. I don't think it's something that a user with 300k+ rep would feel that they're missing on. I would say you're overthinking this. It wasn't an exact copy of their answer and you gave them credit in your answer (which is required). No need to feel guilty.

Comment: @Machavity the OP of the answer can also make it CW by editing and ticking the CW checkbox if they want to.

Comment: @HereticMonkey It's not clear it's off-topic on SO. I wouldn't migrate it

Comment: However, for every new proposal, we always have to think about the possibility of getting abused and its effect (example: sockpuppets, making a "two-party" consent basically a single-party consent, possibly affecting the status of automatic post ban by sending bad posts to the socks)

Comment: @41686d6564 Yeah, I misspoke. Not migrate, close.

Comment: From a legal point of view there isn't really ownership of answers. What maybe could be useful is to convert contributions to community wiki even after creation. Maybe only if they have a positive score.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You give credit through proper attribution. You can argue that just posting a link to the source is maybe cutting it a little short, you may also want to name the username. At the very least link to the exact answer that you quoted content from and not to the question, a question can have multiple answers after all.

But other than that you did what you had to due to an inability to create a cross-site duplicate link, that credit goes to *you*.

---

Conversationally, have you considered the consequences of being able to transfer the ownership of the answer? At that point it will kind of start to look like the new owner is advertising or copying their own answers which may be interpreted as a little shady. The fact that you reference their answer is far more of an endorsement of that answer, in my opinion.

Comment: This is a good answer. A question can within scope at two communities; it can even be answered at one of those communities, weeks or years before it's asked at another.  Since a duplicate shouldn't be migrated to a community (many reasons for this, I am 95% sure the closure of a question, will result in the migration being rejected), proper citation and quotation is the only thing left (since we cannot close as a duplicate of the question at another community).  Now once you have quoted another answer, hopefully, you made the answer your own.